okta login how to display error message when user in provisioned status
Question: Given an Okta user in a provisioned state, when that user attempts to login, then how do we display a custom message to the user? (ex: "Go activate your account!")
Context: My team is using Okta for authentication and also Okta's sign-in widget for the login screen.  We've been using Okta's customization GUI (ie. Okta Admin Dashboard -> Customizations) to provide rudimentary customization to the user login experience.  We have rigorous controls over authentication, but the login page itself is intentionally plain.
Problem: User gets added to our Okta and correctly receives the initial activation email.  However, the user will start getting additional emails from our Okta.  User clicks on subsequent emails, enters their username into the sign-in widget and clicks "Next", then gets a vague "Unable to sign-in" message.  Same deal if the activation link expires.
login error example
We are able to update the user's account as needed.  We do have a few options available for dealing with this edge case.  For example, our users are able to trigger re-sending the activation email to themselves.  However, I'm struggling to figure out a way to indicate to the user that's what they need to do.
We're trying to avoid making an entirely customized sign-in widget, hence the leaning in to Okta's customization GUI.  Do I need to write some JavaScript in the code editor provided by the customization GUI or what??
code editor example
Please and thank you!

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

@ultrapulpo Are you able to read user information during login?
